# select single row from multiple rows by id

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table like the following.

```
  id |  value  |flag
   2    null     1
   2     z       2
   3     x       1
   3     y       2
   3     z       3
   4     null    2
```

I need result like the following

```
   id |  value  |flag
   2     z       2
   3     x       1
   4     null     2
```

If the value is null, the value from other matched id should be taken (2-z-2). If all the rows of an id are not null then the value should be taken by priority which is 1 here (3-x-1). If an id has only null value, take any single  row  with null value and flag does not matter here.

Comment: So by priority you mean the flag column? What if you have multiple ids that match your null value? What have you tried, what didn't work, etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, priority is flag here. I need 1 row for 1 id. If multiple ids have null value only then they will go to separate rows with null value. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will take the value of the first not null value (min flag value)  or the null row otherwise.

**You data:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    ( id INT , val CHAR(1) , flag INT );
INSERT  INTO @table
        ( id, val, flag )
VALUES  ( 2, NULL, 1 )
,       ( 2, 'z', 2 )
,       ( 3, 'x', 1 )
,       ( 3, 'y', 2 )
,       ( 3, 'z', 3 )
,       ( 4, NULL, 2 ); -- NULL only value
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT  id ,
        val ,
        flag
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
            n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE
                                                    WHEN val IS NULL
                                                    THEN 0
                                                    ELSE 1
                                                    END DESC, flag )
          FROM      @table AS t
        ) AS o
WHERE   n = 1;
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` partitions by `id` and for each `id`, it orders by 0 or 1 (null/not null) and `flag`.
The `case` is used to order by `not null` values first (=1) and then by `null` values (=0).

**Output:**

```
id  val     flag
2   z       2
3   x       1
4   NULL    1
```

Comment: Hope  you don't mind, I removed the Quote syntax highlighting you used (which should only be used for quoted text) and replaced it with bold headings and did some SQL formatting while I was at it.

Comment: @Tanner. I don't mind. But I am having a hard time reading code where almost everything is uppercase... And my personnal feeling is that I have to move my eyes a lot while reading it. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Oh no problem I have a SQL tool that does the formatting for me, just fired that at it. Feel free to rollback and edit yourself if required. Main thing was the quote highlighting.

Comment: This is fine like this. Thanks.